# Можно ли before и nth-child совместить?

Tags: html, css

Есть маркированный список. Моя задача нечетным строчкам списка присвоить маркер "звездочка". Я сделал list-style: none; (сделал невидимыми маркеры). И далее пытаюсь совместить nth-child(2n+1) и before, и через content="звездочка" присвоить нечетным (или четным без разницы уже) маркер - "звездочка".
Вопрос - как мне совместить nth-child(2n+1) и before.
В html ничего менять мне нельзя.Только через css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
  color: white;
}

ul {
  margin: 50px;
}

li:nth-child(even):before {
  content: '*';
  color: red;
}

li:nth-child(odd):before {
  content: '1';
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>первый</li>
  <li>второй</li>
  <li>третий</li>
  <li>четвертый</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #00f;
  margin-top: -4px;
}

li:nth-of-type(odd):before {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>list</li>
</ul>
```